# Program stuck in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, semaphore

I was trying to use semaphores in a while loop and my program is running in an infinite loop. Basically I fork off children and use execv to start new user processes. The processes use semaphore in shared memory to communicate.

```
struct shared
{
int count;
sem_t sem;
} *shmem;
void forking()
{
key_t shmkey = ftok("makefile",777);
        if (shmkey == -1) {
            perror("Ftok failed");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // Get our shm id
        shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(shared), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (shmid == -1) {
            perror("Failed to allocate shared memory region");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // Attach to our shared memory
        shmem = (shared*)shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
        if (shmem == (void *)-1) {
            perror("Failed to attach to shared memory region");
            exit(-1);
        }

    sem_init(&(shmem->sem),1,1);
    pid_t PID;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
    PID=fork();
    if(PID==0)
    {
        static char *args[]={"./child",NULL};
        int status;
        if(( status= (execv(args[0], args)))==-1)
        perror("failed to execv");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(PID>0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            sem_wait(&(shmem->sem));
            {
                shmem->count=shmem->count+1;
            }
            sem_post(&(shmem->sem));
        }
    }
    if(PID<0)
    perror("error in fork");
    }
}
main()
{
    forking();
}
```

in child.c

```
struct shared
{
int count;
sem_t sem;
} shmem;
void main()
{
    bool alive=true;
    do
    {
    sem_wait(&(shmem->sem));
    if(shmem->count==5)
    {
        shmem->count=0; 
        alive=false;
    }
    sem_post(&(shmem->sem));
    }while(alive);
}
```

child.c loops endlessly without allowing parent to increment i till 5. This happens even if I comment out while loop in first file and just let it increment without loops.In the end nothing exits.

Comment: `struct shared { int count; sem_t sem; }; shared shmem;` is an error.  You're missing either a `typedef` or a `struct`.

Comment: I was actually using a separate file for the structure and just including it in both the programs. But now its fine i think.

Comment: `shared->count` is poorly named.  It is *not* shared between the parent and the children.  The parent is incrementing a counter in its own process space.  Each child is checking the value of a variable in its process space.

Comment: sorry forgot to add shared data initializing.

Comment: There's nothing in the first file to ever break away from `while(1)`, no flag or condition to break or evaluate to false...

Comment: even if I comment out the semaphores in first file, child.c is still stuck in its while loop. Also, I assumed when parents turn is over the while will stop.

Comment: `if(PID<0)` ??  Why do you only increment the counter if `fork` failed?

Comment: Sorry, my bad that should have been if(PID>0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You are using fork wrong, and definitely not using shared memory.</s>

Here's some few point

1. By calling fork, you are making a copy of parent running in different memory space. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html
2. By using execve, you essentially delete the old memory and replace it with a new one which are not linked in anyway to your parent process. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html

To make your code work, you should be using `pthread_*` instead as it will live in the same memory space and make your global variable volatile as gcc will try to optimize and will have weird behaviors if it does so.

Ok it seems I've missed quite a few points while being not totally wrong on my assumption.

So your child.c is missing quite a few bit of code

1. It does not contains all the initialization you've made in your parent which is necessary because if you use `execve` you essentially lost every memory mapping you've mapped previously in your parent process.
2. Your parents loops infinitely so `shmem->count` will never really equals to 5, you will have to break at some moment or change your condition in your child code.

Here's what your child should look like.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    sem_t sem;
} shared;

shared *shmem;
int shmid;
key_t shmkey;

int main()
{
    int alive=1;

    shmkey = ftok("makefile",777);
    if (shmkey == -1) {
        perror("Ftok failed");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Get our shm id
    shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof *shmem, 0);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to allocate shared memory region");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Attach to our shared memory
    shmem = (shared*)shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
    if (shmem == (shared *)-1) {
        perror("Failed to attach to shared memory region");
        exit(-1);
    }

    do
    {
        sem_wait(&(shmem->sem));
        printf("%d\n", shmem->count);
        if(shmem->count > 5)
        {
            shmem->count=0; 
            alive=0;
        }
        sem_post(&(shmem->sem));
    }while(alive);

    printf("I have finished %u\n", getpid());
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Our class has not reached pthread yet, could you modify my program to show me how pthread works?

Comment: Ok it seems I failed to notice the semaphore, it should be working while in another process but not after execve, let me fix that and I will post also a code working

Comment: Edit: I fixed my answer      @Fairy